# How to check the date and time (visible and hide)from the mysql

Tags: javascript, php

how to check the date and time from the mysql database ...and if the date once entered from the user panel, and other user enter the same date on the box  it will be hide else visible(available)   Eg:(ticket booking ...once the ticket is booked then the seat is disabled else available)

Comment: You can fetch date from database & through php/jquery you will hide the date

Comment: $sqll = "SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `game_id`='$game'";
      $resultt = $con->query($sqll);
      if (!empty($resultt)) {
       $row = $resultt->fetch_array();
       $price = $row['game_price'];
       $name = $row['game_name'];
       $total_price = $price * $count;
       $count = $row['game_'count];
       $new_count = $count - $count;
       if ($new_count < 0) {
        echo "Only ".$count." ".$name." remain in Store";
       }

Comment: exactly but how will calculate the date if the date is already present in the database

Comment: let us know your approach

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple(or mixed) solutions to your problem. I am suggesting following two:

- When a user selects a date make ajax call to check the status and notify the user accordingly.
- Use a [polling mechanism](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) to enable/disable(or show/hide) your date field

These are two basic solutions to your problems, however there could be more "better" solutions available but those would depend on particular use cases. For now you can try these.